# Axios not retreiving data from REST service

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im using React with axios to read some data from my backend.

I have a BetBuilder js using axios to read like this:

```
componentDidMount() {


    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/matches/')
        .then(response => {
            console.log("Dentro do didmount");
            this.setState({ matches: response.data._embedded.matches });
            console.log(this.state.matches);
            console.log("Dentro do didmount");
        });
```

Everything works fine here. So in my render method i pass this data to a Match component:

```
 var matches = this.state.matches.map(match =>
        <Match key={match._links.self.href} match={match}/>
    );
```

In my Match.js class, I try to retrieve other data with axios. But it just doesnt work. In my debug it never enters on the response function.

```
 const awayUrl = this.props.match._links.away.href;
const homeUrl = this.props.match._links.home.href;

axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/matches/4/away")w
  .then(response => {
    console.log("Dentro do away");
    this.setState({ away: response.data._embedded });
    console.log(this.state.away);
    console.log("Dentro do away");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error",error)
  });
```

What Im missing? Theres something on the Axios lifecycle that i cant use it in the same request? Why this axios.get method is never called, and dont throws any exception too?

Thanks

Comment: it's not that extra 'w' is it?  heh. axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/matches/4/away")w

Comment: hehe. Just copy paste problem. Its not this.

Comment: Is your Match component being rendered?  Also, where are you making the http request in the Match component?

Comment: Yes. It is being rendered. IM making the http request in the render() method:

Comment: render() {

    const awayUrl = this.props.match._links.away.href;
    const homeUrl = this.props.match._links.home.href;
    console.log("AXIOS");
    //console.log(axios);
    console.log("AXIOS");


    axiosClasses.get(awayUrl)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Dentro do away");
        this.setState({ away: response.data._embedded });
        console.log(this.state.away);
        console.log("Dentro do away");
      })